# highlighting the TextField with red border on error in struts2

Tags: css, jsp, struts2

I am developing a web page using struts2.I want to highlight my User ID /password textfield with red border and display error message in case wrong username/password

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Stock Portfolio Management</title>
</head>
<FONT COLOR=black><marquee BEHAVIOR=ALTERNATE><h1 ALIGN="center">STOCK PORTFOLIO</h1></marquee></FONT>
 <style type="text/css">
body
{
/* background: url(./image/9.jpg) no-repeat fixed;  */
    /* -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; */
    postion:fixed
}
img
{
position:fixed;
bottom: 20%;
left: 20%;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -100px;
}
#login
{
position:fixed;
top: 20%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -100px;
} 
.errors {
background-color:#FFCCCC;
    border:1px solid #CC0000;
    width:350px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    position:relative;
    left:0pt;
    bottom:10pt;

}

.errors li{ 
    list-style: none; 
}
</style>
<body>
<img src="image/9.jpg" height="250" width="300">
<s:form id="login" action="authenticate" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="userid" key="User Id" size="25" />
    <s:password name="password" label="Password" size="25" />

    <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
    <div class="errors">
      <s:actionerror/>
   </div>
   </s:if> 

   <s:submit method="CheckUser" value="Login" align="center" />  <s:reset value="Reset" align="center" />
    <a href="<s:url action="moveregister" method="execute"/>">New User?</a>
    &nbsp
    <a href="<s:url action="forgotpassword" method="forgot"/>">Forgot Password?</a>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I have in my action class:

```
addActionError(getText("User Id which you provided doesnt exists"));
return "error";
```

As you see I am catching the errors and showing on the screen using the `.errors` and also formating it using the CSS above.

But I want to highlight a the error filed with red border say `userID` field if that is error or password field if that is error. I tried Googling and found many thing like editing your template `class/<s:fielderror>`, etc. but was not able produce.

Comment: Why are there html elements between the head and body elements? (And marquee? Really?)

Comment: Dave Newton yes marqee <FONT COLOR=black><marquee BEHAVIOR=ALTERNATE><h1 ALIGN="center">STOCK PORTFOLIO</h1></marquee></FONT> simple just for design i have kept is taht causing the problem?

Comment: Of course not, but putting stuff you want to see outside of the body tag isn't valid HTML. I'd recommend looking at the HTML emitted from the tag library, looking at the styles applied, and see if they work for you--if they do, simply override the default S2 styles. Chances are they won't if you have anything beyond pretty basic styling. At that point you have a few options, including using the "simple" theme and doing everything manually or in simple wrapper custom tags, or creating your own theme.

Answer (score 3):

First, put all your HTML where it is supposed to be;

Second, decoring fields with red border is usually a convention to show a validation error: for example, a malformed (or out of range) date, a character in a numeric field, a mandatory field left empty, ecc... that validation in Struts2 should be executed by the `ValidationInterceptor`, preferably via XML, adding one error for each field in `<s:fielderrors/>` tag. Your case is different: you pass the validation, you execute your Action's method, but the result is "user not authenticated": in the most of web applications, this would result in a red error message showing up, without decoring username and password field (you should decore them instead if they were left empty...).

But, if you want to decore them, why not using Javascript ?

Add this in CSS style:

```
.decoratedErrorField{
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

add ID to your fields:

```
<s:textfield name="userid" id="userid" key="User Id" size="25" />
<s:password name="password" id="password" label="Password" size="25" />
```

if an error occurred, get your fields by ID and decore them by adding the error class to them;
add this at the end of the page, just before `</body>`:

```
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[                 
            document.getElementById("userid").className += " decoratedErrorField ";
            document.getElementById("password").className += " decoratedErrorField ";
        //]]>
    </script>       
</s:if>
```

Comment: if multiple errors happen multiple times the class will be filled with the decoreatedErrorField.

Comment: Sure, this is just a kick-off example (even if not elegant, having the same class multiple times would not be an *error*, however). Just add a check to see if the class is already there before adding it, and you're good. Note that this answer is from 2012, many things have changed since then, who's not using Bootstrap or similar systems nowadays ? Many frontend frameworks evolved and so did the browsers, so there are probably better out-of-the-box ways to do this, but in case you don't want to lose time, this works. Thanks for the feedback anyway @EduardoDennis